# Remove text duplication on tag badges page

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-badges

If you look at [the (bronze) tag badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=bronze), you'll see the following text repeated a few thousand times:

> Earned at least x total score for at least y answers in the ... tag                  z awarded

Now this seems like unnecessary repetition, and this information is already on the right of the page, can we just simplify it to the below?

[image]

(possibly with a 'Class' column for the colour blind?)

Not to mention that tags can't decide where they want to be:

[image]

And if you view gold with bronze or silver badges, because 1000/200 is longer than 400/80 and 100/20, you get inconsistent spacing for the same words on different lines:

[image]

And similarly the vertical spacing is inconsistent with the difference in lines:

[image]

All of the above would also be fixed by my suggestion.

Comment: It is a bit odd the way it stands (specifically the tag position and the vertical spacing, +1). About your suggestion columns 1 and 2 would be redundant, wouldn't they?. Lastly, there would be less places on SE informing about the badge requirements.

Comment: @AndreSilva It feels like it's a bit redundant, but keep in mind that they're both links (to different places). There would be less places informing about requirements, but informing twice on the same page isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks for clarifying this.